# Are there any species with no Force-sensitives in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

We have seen many species in the *Star Wars* galaxy who are Force-sensitive including Human, Mon Calamari, Wookiee, Twi'lek, etc., but are there any known species whose members are incapable of using the Force? Non-sentient beings, like the Loth-wolf, and non-organic creatures, like the Giants of Living Stone, can be Force-sensitive so is it possible there is a sentient species that has no ability or knowledge of the Force, or would it be safe to assume that any being with some form of consciousness can use the Force in some capacity?

Comment: is being resistant to Force manipulation considered equivalent? (ie Hutt, Toydarian)

Comment: @NKCampbell for this question, no. I do think it would be a good question on it own tho...?

Comment: Do droids count?

Comment: @Spencer I'm sure there was a droid force user, I'll get back to you

Comment: There is a droid in Legends called R5-D4 (Skippy) who was force sensitive and was the red R2 unit the Owen and Luke almost bought before R2-D2 starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid –

Comment: Sarlaccs, dianoga, and ducks are good candidates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Legends continuity, there were two races of beings who were specifically said to not be able to use the Force. The Ssi-ruuk, a race of reptilians from outside the main galactic body, were *completely* separated from, or blind to, the Force. For whatever reason, they were unable to tap into it, feel or use it, and as a result, they were fascinated by the potential of Force-sensitives like Luke Skywalker. The Yuuzhan Vong, also of Legends and also from outside the main Galaxy, were likewise unable to feel or use the Force and, like the Ssi-ruuk, used Force-sensitives to do with the Force what they themselves could not.

From a wider standpoint counting both Legends and Canon, most droids, if you consider them to be "intelligent beings", were unable to interact with the Force since they weren't organic and therefore had no midi-chlorian content. On the other hand, the vast majority of organic beings in the Galaxy were unable to use the Force not because they were blind to it, but because they likewise didn't have the necessary midi-chlorian count to allow them to tap into the Force.

As you said, there were nonsentient and semisentient animals (another, perhaps more accurate difference is sapient vs nonsapient; that is, being able to actively think) that were able to utilize the Force as well. In Legends, the ysalamiri of the planet Myrkr were curious example of this, being able to project a Force-nullifying "bubble" to keep themselves from being hunted by the Force-attuned vornskrs that roamed the planet's forests; ysalamiri were used in the Legends continuity to prevent Force-users from being able to tap into the Force. (As a side note, ysalamiri were put back into the canon proper with *Star Wars Rebels* but so far they haven't been said to retain the Force-nullifying ability of their Legends counterparts.)

Comment: Don't forget using ysalamiri to grow clones at an accelerated rate without driving them insane.

Answer (score 4):

According to Legends the [**Rakata**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rakata) (or 'Builders') also aren't Force sensitive but they lost their Force sensitivity because of a plague.

The [**Rakata**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rakata) are in my opinion an especially interesting species because in Legends they are the first that made/used Blasters and everything that *Star Wars* is famous for (Blasters, Lightsabers, Force use, ...)